# Unexpected behavior when repeatedly calling map.setZoom with the same zoom level (Leaflet.js)

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've found that repeatedly calling `map.setZoom()` immediately after a `fitBounds` results in a sort of zoom "toggle", where it will toggle between the specified zoom level and a close-up of the bounds. [Here is a](https://jsfiddle.net/8x74nwur/) js fiddle which demonstrates the behavior I'm talking about. Hitting the "Zoom it" button 3-5 times shows first a zoom to the desired zoom level, then a close zoom in, and then a zoom back to the desired level, ad infinitum. Is this expected behavior, a bug, or something else?